# How to refer to prefixed CSS class?

Tags: css

For legacy reasons, my CSS class is has a `.x` prefix:

```
.x input.myclass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I'm not familiar with this syntax, how can I use this class in an HTML element? None of the below work:

```
<input type='text' class='myclass'>
<input type='text' class='x myclass'>
<input type='text' class='.x myclass'>
<input type='text' class='.x.mylcass'>
<input type='text' class='x.mylcass'>
```

Comment: that's a descendant selector. Please spend [more time researching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/497418) CSS syntax.

Comment: The only CSS prefixes I'm aware of are `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-o-`, and `-ms-` and what you have above isn't close to that.

Comment: @zzzzBov's is right: if you read, say, the [MDN article on CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), you would have had the knowledge to answer your own question. Looking at your other `css` questions, it seems like there are others that you could also solve by reading some docs first.

Comment: @j08691 it's pretty normal for someone in a new technology to not know the right terminology. In the general sense of "prefix", yes, `.x` is a prefix. In the css sense, no, it definitely isn't. It seemed pretty clear to me what he was trying to communicate, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.x input.myclass {
    // css goes here
}
```

The above CSS will affect any input tag with a class of `myclass` **wrapped inside** any containing block of class `x`

Therefore it will match the pattern below:

```
<div class="x">
    <input type="text" class="myclass" />
</div>
```